# flake8 conditional with python version in stub file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flake8, python-typing, pyi

I need to support both python 3.8 and versions lower that 3.8, but the package I need to import into my stub (*.pyi) file had different name in <3.8

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.minor < 8:
    import xyz
else:
    import zyx
```

In general this should do the job, but when I run flake8 with *.pyi files config (`flake8 --config flake8-pyi.ini`) I get this:

`Y002 If test must be a simple comparison against sys.platform or sys.version_info`

Any ideas what could be done about that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [the description of flake8-pyi](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-pyi/) (a flake8 plugin, not part of flake8 itself):

> Y002: If test must be a simple comparison against sys.platform or sys.version_info. Stub files support simple conditionals to indicate differences between Python versions or platforms, but type checkers only understand a limited subset of Python syntax, and this warning triggers on conditionals that type checkers will probably not understand.

The fix is to change your condition to:

```py
if sys.version_info < (3, 8):
```

note that your code would break for `2.8` (yes, some people do this!) and `4.0` so you should be careful with eliding parts of comparisons ;) -- I've written a flake8 plugin which helps lint against conditions that might be problematic: [flake8-2020](https://github.com/asottile/flake8-2020)